# How to query MySQL column against a posted variable?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am trying to see whether a connected database has an email that matches the one posted by user:

```
app.post("/forgot_password", (req, res, next) => {

try {
const { emailId }  = req.body;
db.query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = ?", async (error, results) => {
if (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
if (emailId != results) {
  //Change to pop up saying incorrect email
  res.render("forgot_password")
  return
}
})

} catch (error) {
console.log(error)
}
})
```

How can I check if any of the data in column "email" match the "emailId" const that is posted here by the here:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="emaild" id="email">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got to supply the variable to the query

```
const { emailId }  = req.body;
db.query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = ?", [emailId], async (error, results) => {
```

Notice that I added a parameter to the query function. Its signature is:

```
db.query(sqlString, arrayOfParameters, callbackFuntion)
```

Here's a link to the documenation:
https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#performing-queries

The query return an array of rows from the database where the email column matches the value of emailId. I assuume emailId is the actual email the user supplied e.g. *myname@domain.com*

The results should be only one row since I assume different users can't have the same email.

So to check if the email matches, simply verify that the number of rows is 1

```
const { emailId }  = req.body;
db.query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = ?", [emailId], async (error, results) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return // we want to exit the function
  } 

  // so you can see what the results are
  console.log(results) 
  if (results.length === 1) {  
    console.log('the user supplied an email that exists in our database')
  } else {
    console.log('no email found', emailId)
  } 
})
```

Comment: I see, I have added the parameter to the query but I still cannot match the emailId against the column results. I suspect because "results" gives me the entire column rather than checking if any of the rows would match the ID, how can I search against each one rather than the column as a whole?

Comment: Thank you the above solution worked. Although I tried it before, I found the "name" of the input in html had a typo hence wouldn't find a match for the email